# How to Change/Modify Content of Slider in Magento 2 PWA

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I have setup venia theme in Magento 2.3 instance. But, now I want to change and add some content in product slider.

I want to also know that from where these content load and display.

How can I change it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]